# JVM argument to provide ehcache.xml location

Tags: java, ehcache

I'm looking for a way to provide to my web application an external location of ehcache.xml, I have already tried to put the ehcache.xml in several locations but is not picked up, the evidence is :

```
WARN  net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory  - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from 
ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: bundleresource://someid/ehcache-failsafe.xml
```

I tried the WEB-INF folder and the resources folder of the maven project.

But no avail does anyone know a way to provide it through JVM arguments?

Answer (score 0):

If your application uses Hibernate as ORM framework [Ehcache](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/integrations/hibernate.html) configuration file can be configured via the .cfg.xml file.

```
<property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">file:////path-to-ehcache.xml</property>
```